# Distribtuing free software without source code

Tags: windows

Is their some place like Source Forge where I can distribute a free Windows application without also giving away the source code?

I have some concerns about Open Source distribution.  Mostly the people who take a good simple app and tweak and fiddle with it until its dysfunctional or lost its original purpose or a flaky over worked monster with too many glitches.  This can ruin an app's reputation and functionality.  I wholly support the idea of giving away software you write I just don't fully agree with giving away the source code too.

Comment: By definition of *Free Software* you are making the source code available (and improvable). You could indeed distribute the binaries separately. But don't call it "free software" if you don't give the exact source code (call it "freeware" if you don't want to give source code -which is a mistake-, and dont use http://sourceforge.net/ for non-free software "freeware").

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: "*free software*" does not imply "*OpenSource Source software*". As long you everybody can use it without restrictions it's fair enough to call it "free".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software

Comment: Free software on http://sourceforge.net/ *should be* open-source. If you don't give the source code (under some free software license) you should distribute it outside of `sourceforge`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Software “everybody can use […] without restrictions” is what we have the name “freeware” for.

Answer (score 2):

Just open a free site (like wordpress or godaddy) and put your binaries there. You need to upload them to the server, then publish a link to them ("New version available!").

Answer (score 0):

Try MajorGeeks, Which in my opinion is a reputable download site.

http://majorgeeks.com/